# Keycloak UserRegistrationProvider REGISTER_ERROR

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to write keycloak user id to external database on registration, but keycloak crashes even without database call.

addUser code is already simplified to bare minimum:

```
    @Override
    public UserModel addUser(RealmModel realm, String username) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        
        UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(
                this.keycloakSession,
                realm,
                this.componentModel,
                uuid
        );

        adapter.setUsername(username);

        return adapter;
    }
```

I just create UserAdapter, set my own generated UUID and return it like it's done in many guides/code examples.

UserAdapter is:

```
public class UserAdapter extends AbstractUserAdapterFederatedStorage {
    protected String keycloakId;
    protected String username;

    public UserAdapter(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, ComponentModel storageProviderModel, String uid) {
        super(session, realm, storageProviderModel);
        keycloakId = StorageId.keycloakId(storageProviderModel, uid);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return keycloakId;
    }
}
```

But on registration i get those errors from keycloak:

1. `WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-2) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: java.lang.RuntimeException: No user model provided for persisting changes`
2. `WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-2) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=product, clientId=spa, userId=null, ipAddress=192.168.208.1, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, redirect_uri=http://product.test/, authSessionParentId=3ccd3825-8ba1-4d26-8a00-bdfb968f442c, authSessionTabId=CchD1Kp-5Lo`

As i understand my UserAdapter is faulty, and sure login fails after user store failed, but i can't understand what's wrong, i've already tried to set a break points with logs and till return from addUser everything looks kind of good?

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem because I had overridden the `getUserById()` method from `UserLookupProvider` interface.

When registering a user, you go through several classes - depending on your Keycloak registration configuration :

- `RegistrationUserCreation` (where the `addUser` method is called)
- `RegistrationPassword` (where the `updateCredential` method is called)
- `RegistrationProfile`

In both `RegistrationPassword` and `RegistrationProfile` classes, the user is retrieve using the overridden `getUserById()` method. Depending on how you've implemented it, it might return `null`. In my case it was calling an external API, but the user was not saved, yet.

Your error message might be thrown from the `RegistrationProfile` class